# SQL Server: how can i generate unique random number at each row of record?

Tags: sql-server, random, sql-server-2000

I'm using SQL Server 2000. I'd like to generate random number without repetition at each row. However, my code is not working. I tried many times but i cannot fix the repetition problem. My code as below: I used "case" to handle duplicate number but not work. Anyone can help me? So much Thanks!

```
DECLARE @index INT
    ,@ran_no INT
    ,@counter INT
    ,@i INT

SET @i = 1

WHILE @i <= 18
BEGIN
    SELECT @index = count(basket_seq)
    FROM dbo.test
    WHERE basket_seq = @i
        AND flag = 'left'

    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.test
        SET @ran_no = convert(INT, 1 + @index * RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())))
            ,@ran_no = (
                CASE 
                    WHEN convert(INT, 1 + @index * RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))) NOT IN (
                            SELECT seq_no
                            FROM dbo.test
                            WHERE basket_seq = @i
                                AND flag = 'left'
                            )
                        THEN @ran_no
                    END
                )
            ,seq_no = @ran_no
        WHERE basket_seq = @i
            AND flag = 'left'
    END

    SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

Comment: Why you use case statement? just explain

Comment: because i want to check whether that random number already exists in the column "seq_no".                                                                           CASE 
WHEN convert(INT, 1 + @index * RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))) NOT IN (SELECT seq_no FROM dbo.test WHERE basket_seq = @i AND flag = 'left')

Comment: i didn't think NEWID() existed in SQL 2000.

Comment: random is a requirement or the goal is to have a unique number? the question is because you wrote 'i'd like to' like if this was a wish and not a requirement.

Comment: actually, i want to assign unique number to each row of record. If i just add sequence number(1,2,3,4..........) to each record, I'm afraid it would show the same records every times. So i tried to assign unique random number.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RandNumber -- you can set @ran_no with this value in your sql query.
FROM   (
           SELECT ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(6)) %500) + 1 RandNumber  --To set max limit number you can replace 500 with any number.
           FROM   sysobjects
       )            SAMPLE
GROUP BY
       RandNumber
```

As you said, you want to set value in seq_no, in your query you have set @ran_no to seq_no so you should try like below.

```
SET    @ran_no        = (SELECT TOP 1 ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(6)) %1000) + 1 FROM   sysobjects)
```

To generate random number without repetition at each row. Try something like above. will help you.

Comment: still have duplicate random number. i want to update the column " seq_no" with unique random number.

Comment: @wing91 - I don't think it will have duplicate random number.

Comment: there is an error. we cannot set more than 1 value into @ran_no.                  update  dbo.test 
set  seq_no = (SELECT ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(6)) % @index) + 1 FROM   sysobjects)
where basket_seq = @i  and flag = 'left'

Comment: I think you made some mistake in your query, can you provide the whole query here, so I can get the idea why this error is occurred.

Comment: <code>Declare @index int, @i int
set @i = 1
while @i <= 18
begin
select @index=count(basket_seq) from dbo.test where basket_seq = @i and flag = 'left'
begin
update  dbo.test
set  seq_no = (SELECT ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(6)) % @index) + 1 FROM   sysobjects)
where basket_seq = @i  and flag = 'left'
end
set @i = @i + 1
end<code>

Comment: Declare @index int, @i int set @i = 1 while @i <= 18 begin select @index=count(basket_seq) from dbo.test where basket_seq = @i and flag = 'left' begin update dbo.test set seq_no = (SELECT TOP 1  ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(6)) % @index) + 1 FROM sysobjects) where basket_seq = @i and flag = 'left' end set @i = @i + 1 end    - Try this one

Comment: Thank you for your help. But still have duplicate number. The problem is there is no "if-condition" to filter out the same number. For example, generate "14" in row1 and you cannot ensure it would not generate "14" again in row2.

Answer (score 0):

Just check this [link](http://p2p.wrox.com/sql-server-2000/50223-generate-random-number-ms-sql-server-2000-a.html)

```
 SELECT RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY))
   FROM dbo.SysObjects
```

For your update statement, use like this.

```
update  dbo.test
set seq_no =  RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY)) --directly given this function here, 
where basket_seq = @i  and flag = 'left'
```

Also as per [MSDN link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238382%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) you can use Random function too for Sqlserver2000.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/29/sql-server-random-number-generator-script-sql-query/

Comment: this query would update all record with the same value.

Comment: Sorry. I dont know what you mean. Can you explain more to me? i'm beginner in sql. :(  Thank you for your help

Comment: my last questions is, do you want random no. or sequence like 1,2,3..... as per record?

Comment: dear random no and sequence is 2 different thing.. so sequence itself random no list...so correct me as I understand that you want 1,2,3... sequence for your table entries? right!